# How can I fix a screen door that sticks?

Tags: screens, doors, lubrication

I have a sliding screen door that leads out to a porch/deck.  The door continually sticks and is just doesn't slide open cleanly.  Otherwise the screen and everything is fine.  Is there something I can do to fix this or do I need to replace the entire screen door?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried lubricating it? [Seems worth a shot for the price](http://www.shopgetorganized.com/item/PATIO_DOOR_LUBE_AND_SLIDE/29338?src=GOFRGL08&CAWELAID=281651816) before replacing the whole door.

Comment: I wasn't aware that there was a lube avaliable for sliding doors! I would have just sprayed it with copious amounts of WD-40

Comment: @Farseeker: That was my first thought too, before I consulted Google.

Comment: Will definitely try to try this out and report back!

Comment: @brendan: I might even be tempted to go with Farseeker's idea first if you've got some WD-40 lying around.

Answer (score 1):

My Dad used to use Ivory soap!  It worked very well but with any thick lubricant it needed to be wiped off and replaced now and then because it would collect dirt.  Use as little as possible to get the screen running smoothly along the track by moving the screen back & forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a silicone spray lubricant. One I've used is called Blaster though there are other brands. You want to use a lubricant that does not leave a film.  Just ask the clerk and they will know what you are looking for.  WD40 would be the worst thing to use for this on many levels.  You don't want to leave a film once you spray the surface because it will be messy and attract dirt and grime.  This stuff will do the trick and has multiple uses around the house such as windows to help them slide easier and your garage door hinges.

Comment: Actually, the [MSDS for Blaster][https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blastercorporation.com%2Fimages%2Fmsds%2FPB_50_aerosol_oct10.pdf] suggests naptha (a cleaner) and oil, no silicone.

Answer (score -1):

Take your screen to a glass company. They usually have or can get replacement rollers.